# Compile and run dotty code using doc command

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

I have cloned [dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/contributing/getting-started.html) and add it to my PATH (I'm Linux user) after that I created HelloWorld project using dotty and trying to compile and run it using `dotc` and `dotr` commands, as following:

```
dotc HelloWorld.scala
dotr HelloWorld
```

I got this error :

```
naseem@naseem-Satellite-C850-B177:~/Desktop/hellodotty/src/main/scala$ dotc Main.scala 
Building Dotty...
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project dotty-build-build from build.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/staging/00a36f6d792ab07b62c5/dotty/project/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/staging/00a36f6d792ab07b62c5/dotty/project/project/"), "dotty-build-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/staging/00a36f6d792ab07b62c5/dotty/project/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Loading settings for project dotty-build from plugins.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/staging/00a36f6d792ab07b62c5/dotty/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/staging/00a36f6d792ab07b62c5/dotty/project/"), "dotty-build")...
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.9.0/jars/sbt-buildinfo.jar ...
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.jsuereth/sbt-pgp/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.0.0/jars/sbt-pgp.jar ...
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/pl.project13.scala/sbt-jmh/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.2/jars/sbt-jmh.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] pl.project13.scala#sbt-jmh;0.3.2!sbt-jmh.jar (3693ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.9.0!sbt-buildinfo.jar (4591ms)
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jsuereth#sbt-pgp;2.0.0!sbt-pgp.jar (5110ms)
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/naseem/.sbt/1.0/staging/00a36f6d792ab07b62c5/dotty/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Loading settings for project dotty from build.sbt ...
[info] Resolving key references (15750 settings) ...
[info] Set current project to dotty (in build file:/home/naseem/dotty/)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create directory .vscode
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.createDirectory(IO.scala:326)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyImpl(IO.scala:763)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.$anonfun$copy$1(IO.scala:754)
[error]     at scala.Function$.$anonfun$tupled$1(Function.scala:77)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copy(IO.scala:754)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.copyDirectory(IO.scala:800)
[error]     at Build$.$anonfun$globalSettings$2(Build.scala:190)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$andThen$1(Function1.scala:52)
[error]     at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:485)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:840)
[error]     at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Could not create directory .vscode
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are reading tutorial "Getting Started" for contributors

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/contributing/getting-started.html

Just in case, if you are interested not in contributing but in writing HelloWorld you can try reading "Getting Started" for users

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/getting-started.html

Comment: it gives me the same, at the end I need to use the above command to compile and run !!

Comment: @NaseemMahasneh Did you try `sbt new ...`, `sbt clean compile`, `sbt run` (as advised in the tutorial)?